# What concerns should I be aware of when hosting Wordpress/PHP on IIS 7.5 and Server 2008 R2?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am considering moving a Wordpress install to a server running Server 2008 R2. It seems that Microsoft has done some to make running PHP more palatable, but I really haven't seen any recent data or real life test cases.

Comment: Well, you won't have mod_rewrite for the nice URLs, so you'll have to find and use the IIS equivalent.

Comment: IIS7 has a good url rewrite extension. I am excited in this regard because one of the blogs I am moving was on IIS6 and url rewriting was a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS doesn't have issues with threading per se. IIS uses an app pool to process requests. Make sure you install the NTS VC9 version of PHP and you are fine.

WordPress on IIS 7.5 works great btw. Easiest way to install it is here, http://web.ms/wordpress. You can either RDP into your server and install or install it to your local machine using WebMatrix, get it configured all locally then deploy it to your server using WebMatrix's publishing feature. This is especially easy if your hosting provider supports Microsoft's WebDeploy.

Answer (score 1):

I recently setup a wordpress install on a 2008 r2 server... Everything works fine apart from email... Wordpress is set to send mail via sendmail/phpmail - so rather you need to make it so that wordpress sends via SMTP.
Other than that - I had no problems at all :)

Comment: I know IIS6 had a threading issue with PHP. I am just wondering if anyone had noticed performance limitations, snafus when setting up...